# Webrequest not working in a Windows Service

Tags: c#

I am not able to use Webrequest in a windows service. It fails with error ""Unable to connect to the remote server".

```
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
  NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("myuname","mypassword","mydomain");
  request.Proxy.Credentials = nc;

  try
  {

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    //ex.Message is "Unable to connect to the remote server"
  }
```

The code works perfectly fine if it is a console application.

Could someone please tell if there is a fix?

Comment: What user is the service running under?

Comment: tried running as a local system account, as well as under my account. both have the same problem. i also have hard coded my name and password, and use networkcrednetial

Comment: PS : there is a web proxy which requires authentication, hence i use netwrokcredential

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try specifying the [proxy server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) on the request object you've created. When you run the console application I believe that the system looks up your IE configuration for you and the proxy may be set. If the service is running under an account other than yours it might not have the proxy set.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem. After lots of R&D a solution worked for me.

Instead of:

```
WebResponse responseObject = requestObject.GetResponse();
```

I wrote:

```
WebResponse responseObject = null;
responseObject = requestObject.GetResponse();
```

and it worked fine.

I am also looking for the exact reason behind this behavior.